# DCLCD DCL9C Monitor power issues

Tags: display, hardware-failure, troubleshooting, lcd, capacitor

Lately my DCLCD DCL9C monitor has had some troubles. In order to use it I had to toggle the power button upwards of 20 times. Hitting the power button would show the proper display for a second and go black.

I googled the issue and several forum posts pointed me in the direction of bad capacitors. I opened it up but none of them seem too obvious. I'd love some input from someone more knowledgeable to help me identify which, if any, are damaged.

[image: capacitors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your capacitors look fine, to give you an idea, this is how bad capacitors would look:

[image: Swollen capacitors]

These are bad enough they could cause problems, if they're leaking then they're definitely dead.

As for your problem, it's hard to tell. Monitors aren't very serviceable in most cases, replacement parts being hard to source and replacement monitors not being too expensive. Without knowing more about your problem and the age of your monitor, it's hard to say. A few options:

If your monitor turns on but is extremely dark, to the point you can't actually make anything out, it's possible your backlight or inverter has failed.

If the power LED doesn't even come on, it's possible the power supply or mainboard for the monitor has failed.

Either way, it's unlikely to be a simple fix and as stated, your capacitors look fine. I would opt for just replacing the monitor.